# Three variables look like a word

Tags: math-mode

Sometimes when I type in LaTeX something like this: `$e^{int}$` where i is the imaginary number, n an natural number and say t is time, it looks like I'm writting the word 'int'.

Is there any way to make this look better? Thank you.

Comment: `$\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nt}$` maybe?

Comment: i'm more used to seeing the "i" following a number, so maybe rearrange the elements of the superscript.  (of course, "nit" wouldn't really be any better.)

Comment: I agree with barbara: if you feel that an ambiguity can arise, change the order, for instance `e^{nti}`; or change `n` to `k` (throughout, of course).

Comment: Or may be add parenthesis or `\cdot` at some tricky places.

Comment: Usually, named constants (such as `$\mathrm{i}$`) come last, as if a variable affected by a list of coefficients.  `$\mathrm{e}^{nt\mathrm{i}}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a singe space between i,n and n,t using `\,` or use the form `\exp{(int)}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).